# Python: os.system() redirecting stdout to file in home directory fails

Tags: python, image, scanning, os.system

I used the following command :

```
os.system('scanimage > ~/test.pnm')
```

but I can't find the image.

Any suggestions?

Comment: does it work in the shell?

Comment: actually I'm new to python. can you be more specific?

Comment: try the command in the terminal

Comment: The `>` operator **always** creates a file, even when the command fails (the file is opened before the command is run). After executing `os.system(...)` you **must** have `test.pnm` inside your home directory. It might be empty, but it must be there. If it's not, it means that `os.system(...)` gets never called.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, I can't find the file even though the scanner did the scan !
and also when I use a location path (/home/test.pnm) 
it gives me an error : cannot find /root/home/test.pnm : Directory nonexistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe ~ is not expanded. Try

```
 os.system("scanimage > $HOME/test.pnm")
```

and

```
 os.system("scanimage > /tmp/test.pnm")
```

Or if you are running as a different UNIX user (root) the home is not what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that ~ was the problem